# Customizing Turtlebot3: opencr position

Tags: navigation, odometry, ros-kinetic, opencr, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to customize turtlebot3. I moved opencr in other place on robot's base, not the center. Here is my questions:

1. Since imu is located on opencr, Does it have affect to odom data? Or does imu data have affect to odometry data?
2. If it does, which part of opencr code should I modificate to get odom data correct? I mean "/odom" topic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339255/customizing-turtlebot3:-opencr-position/) by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found that place in opencr code, where imu have affect to odometry.

I decided to move opencr as it was located by default, on the center between wheels, instead of changing code in opencr.

---

Originally posted by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) with karma: 83 on 2019-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This depeds a lot on what slam / localization you use. Can you describe which software you call?

Assuming you use the `turtlebot3` repo and your slam and localization is properly configured, you have to edit the `imu_joint` in [this file](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/master/turtlebot3_description/urdf/turtlebot3_burger.urdf.xacro#L129).

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2019-12-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-12-05**:
does slam/localization actually use `/imu` topic or `imu_joint` frame? I thought they only use `/odom` topic as numbers and `odom` frame

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-12-06**:
I use rtabmap, as I know rtabmap does not read `/imu` topic, only `/odom,` right?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It will change the value of angular velocities and accelerations, yes. However if you're just using the orientation output, that actually doesn't matter, especially if its just moved but in the same orientation, because of rigid body transformations.

A rotation of a part is a rotation of a whole. This doesn't hold true for the other values which are used in the IMU to calculate orientation if you use them externally.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-12-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2019-12-05**:
thanks for clarification, but anyway, can you show me exact file in turtlebot3 opencr code, where IMU data have affect to odom topic?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-12-05**:
No idea, I'm not a turtlebot user. I'm just your friendly neighborhood IMU user.